# How do I configure my tty session such that a form feed `\f` character will clear the terminal?

Tags: debian, serial-port

I'm connecting to a USB-serial connection on /dev/ttyACM0. The code on the sender side is sending a `\f` character at regular intervals.

```
    print("----------------------------\n\r");
    print("-- LED CONTROLLER 00.01   --\n\r");
    print("----------------------------\n\r");
    print("\n\f");
```

However, when I run `cat /dev/ttyACM0` from console, the output scrolls down my screen instead of refreshing at the top.

I've dug through the current `stty` settings (by typing `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 -a`) which gives the following output:

```
speed 115200 baud; rows 0; columns 0; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^A; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V;
flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr -icrnl -ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
-opost -olcuc -ocrnl -onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt -echoctl -echoke
```

Reading the `stty --help` page gives the form feed delay (`ff0`), but doesn't indicate how to change anything else. I also found [this page](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/stty.html) which indicates that I can set the FormFeed character like so `FormFeed=014`, but that syntax didn't work for my stty version (`stty --version` gives `stty (GNU coreutils) 8.5`).

Putty in Windows exhibits the correct behaviour, but I'm struggling to get this to work in Debian 6. Does anyone know how I can configure stty to interpret a form feed as a terminal clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the form feed character (`\f`) with proper [ANSI Escape codes](http://c-faq.com/osdep/termcap.html).

You can do this with [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/):

```
sed 's/\f/\o33[2J\o33[0;0H/g' /dev/ttyACM0
```

In detail: `\033[2J` Clear screen, `\033[0;0H`: Go to pos 0,0

(If this does not work, try  `tail -f /dev/ttyACM0 | sed 's/\f/\o33[2J\o33[0;0H/g'`)

EDIT: as [@MarkReel commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74153/how-do-i-configure-my-tty-session-such-that-a-form-feed-f-character-will-clea/74207?noredirect=1#comment1234065_74207), you can use for non-GNU sed version (e.g. BSD sed) ANSI escaped strings:

```
sed $'s/\f/\e[2J\e[0;0H/g' /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: I believe the FPGA is not sending the two characters `backslash` and `f`, but the correct control byte 0x0C.

Comment: @eppesuig Yes, but sed interprets escape codes in its arguments. So it really replaces 0x0C.

Comment: How would this be used? Is the `sed` command going to return the result to the stdout, so I would use this in replacement of `cat`?

Comment: @StaceyAnne Yes, `sed` writes to `stdout`. It behaves like `cat`: It either reads from the file in its arguments list or from `stdin`.

Comment: @jofel it seems that sed does not interpret control character. The following command show it: `echo "\f" | sed 's/\f/formfeed received/g'`. In your example it should not match the line while it matches the line.

Comment: @eppesuig, but don't you need `echo -e "\f"` in order to tell echo that it must echo \f as the special character instead of just \ and f? this: `echo -e "\f" | sed 's/\f/formfeed received/g'` returns `formfeed received` for me.

Comment: @StaceyAnne, my fault, since I tried it on a Mac, using a different sed (bsd instead of gnu). It seems that really gnu sed matches control characters. I think that this answer is the right one, then, since you may use it and filter what you read from ttyACM0 in order to translate formfeed in ansi escape sequences. Did you tried it? Does it really works as it should?

Comment: @eppesuig, yes, it works. I made an alias `alias pserial="sed 's/\f/\o33[2J\o33[0;0H/g'"` so now I can type `pserial /dev/ttyACM0` and not have to remember the whole long thing (or look it up in my history each time) :D

Comment: You can use an ANSI string and then you don't need sed to be the GNU version: `sed $'s/\f/\e[2J\e[0;0H/g'` works with the stock BSD sed.

Answer (score 2):

GNU sed is not essential for solving this problem (though the script is easier to read).  A minimal script is (tested with Solaris and OSX):

```
sed -e 's/^L/^[[H^[[J/g'
```

where `^L` and `^[` are the literal control characters for form-feed <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and escape <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>.  You can insert those in a file using `vi` (for inserting the escape character, first type <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>).

The escape sequences are used to

- move the cursor to the home position `^[[H` and
- clear the display `^[[J`

A few notes:

- it is not necessary to give the row and column in the `^[[H` escape (and in any case, the positions start with **1**, not **0**), and
- if the screen were cleared *before* moving the cursor, a `2` would be needed in the escape, e.g., `^[[2J`, because that clears the entire display.  The default `^[[J` clears from the current position to the end of the display.  A few nonstandard terminals, e.g., `ansi.sys` did not make that distinction.

Some people are confused by bash's use of `^L` for a keyboard shortcut to clear the screen, as well as PuTTY's interpretation of `^L` (see [Why doesn't the screen clear when I type control/L?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_form_feed) in the XTerm FAQ).

Further reading:

- [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)
- [sed - stream editor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found a lot of references online that say bash should interpret `\f` as a clear screen. And just as many saying it doesn't work.

You may be able to mess with your `stty` settings to get it to interpret `\f` properly (which in this context would be written as `^L` for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>). But I couldn't find anything obvious.

A workaround would be to change your code. But there is no [easy, cross-platform way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228617/how-do-i-clear-the-console-in-both-windows-and-linux-using-c) to clear the screen. However, there are [many ways](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/) to choose from. If possible, you can link in a curses library and use that. Or stdlib.h and use `system()`.

Personally, the way I've always done it, is to just send the [ANSI Escape Code](http://c-faq.com/osdep/termcap.html):

```
printf("\033[2J");
```

I'm pretty sure bash will interpret this just fine. And you just need to make sure to turn on ANSI/VT100 compatibility when using PuTTY or Hyperterminal.

Comment: unfortunately I can't do anything too elaborate from the sender side, because the sender device is an FPGA-based microcontroller that I'm trying to keep as small as possible. However, the ANSI escape code will definitely be a viable option if I can convince stty to turn on ANSI (or even better, if it's enabled by default). PS: fancy seeing you on this side of the SE world

Comment: @StaceyAnne The *nix side shouldn't have trouble with the ANSI codes. It's usually the Windows side that requires extra configuration. Though it might be a good idea to do `stty term=vt100`. And I kind of assumed you'd be coming from an FPGA ;-) I figured you would be able to use a big library but included it to make a more complete answer.

Comment: _bash_ interprets Ctrl-L: If you _type_ Ctrl-L and there is a bash running, then it clears the screen. But here, the Ctrl-L (`\f`) is not a keystroke, and it's not interpreted by a bash.

Comment: @Uwe I understand. But I can get the same behavior with `echo -e "\f"`. Though I don't fully understand the mechanism by which is does so. Is that telling bash to interpret the escape code as a Ctrl keystroke?

Comment: @embedded.kyle No, it seems that your terminal program receives the Ctrl-L and reacts by clearing the screen. Probably it's not a bash issue. I can't reproduce this behaviour with a bash running in either xterm or konsole. What terminal program are you using?

Comment: the command echo -e "\f" instruct the echo command to send to its stdout the control character formfeed, while the command echo "\f" instruct the echo command to send a backslash followed by an f.

Comment: @embedded.kyle I also want to know what terminal you're using, because `echo -e "\f"` doesn't work in any of my terminals.

Comment: @Uwe & Stacy - That was my bad. Too many connections open. Forgot what was what. Connection to my Debian box happened to be through PuTTY so I was seeing the clear screen behavior.

Comment: adding `printf("\033[2J")` to my code works, but it refreshes at the bottom of the screen instead of the top, which is interesting.

Comment: I fixed this by also printing `print("\033[0;0H:")` so that it goes back to the beginning.

Comment: @StaceyAnne Learning the intricacies of the [ANSI Escape Sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) is well worth your time. You can create some very nice terminal interfaces to work with embedded projects.

Answer (score 1):

When your FPGA execute the `print("\n\f")` it is really sending two bytes on its stdout, the first one is a linefeed and the second one is a formfeed. These bytes are 0x0A and 0x0C.

Then, the stdout is trasferred over the USB cable, and read via an emulated serial device. This serial device will just trasfer both bytes to the controlling terminal (because you are reading it via the `cat` command), and eventually to your gnome-terminal, xterm or any other program you are using. This terminal emulator have to understand both bytes and act accordingly.

So, you have to check the capabilities of your emulator. Which one are you using?

Comment: Ah. You make a good point. I'm using LXDE and so LXterminal is the one I use the most. Trying `echo -e "\f"` in the terminal doesn't clear the screen, which explains why it hasn't been working. I've tried xterm, LXterminal, and the terminal I get when I go CTL-ALT-F1 which identifies as "linux" accoring to $TERM, and all three of those don't work.

Comment: At least, the xterm manual page at http://www.xfree86.org/current/ctlseqs.html seems to clarify the while in VT100 emulation a formfeed is translated in a linefeed.

Comment: I would really like to change the mode that the xterm runs in, but I'm not really sure how to generate the control characters in xterm using my keyboard. I tried `ESC-[->-0`, but I think I'm way off base with that.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is about the correct emulation of an ANSI terminal, I think the best option you have is to connect to the serial-to-USB converter with `minicom`. Just remember to open the serial device without initialising the modem, i.e., without sending hayes commands on startup.

Comment: I've tried `minicom` and it displayed nothing. My command was `minicom -o -D /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200`. Is `-o` the correct way to bypass modem initialisation?

Comment: These settings are the same as shown from your first `stty` command, so, yes, they seems right. Does minicom show the serial line status (connected or disconnected)? Does this status change when you disconnect the serial cable from the USB converter?

Comment: I did setup with `minicom -s` and added the extra lines to the config to disable modem initialisation. if I run `cat /dev/ttyACM0` it works. Then I run `minicom` which gives "Online" at the bottom, with correct settings, but no data. `CTRL-A X` exits minicom. then `cat` doesn't work anymore :(. Cable removal switches from `Online` to `Offline` as expected, but minicom doesn't recover from cable insertion right away. Had to exit minicom and re-try for it to detect port again. Found it on ~3rd retry.

Comment: cat recovers with cable removal and re-insertion, which I would imagine flushes whatever buffer is getting confused. Very much running out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Sadly, I have no other suggestions beside checking all serial settings.

Comment: I discovered that Linux was defaulting to another USB-serial driver instead of the correct one. A blacklist in modprobe did the trick :)

Comment: @StaceyAnne and does minicom works as expected? I mean, clearing the display when receiving a formfeed?